# python reddit praw psraw got decode json Value Error

Tags: python, json, praw, reddit

I'm trying to get subreddit's content and comments and write them into txt files.
One file will be each post's comments and another one will list each post's related information.
However, I got these errors after the 7250 results and there are 36k+ results I need to get.

I'm also using praw 4.6, because after updated to 5.0, psraw cannot work though.

Error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/untitled/subreddit psraw.py", line 12, in <module>
    for submission in psraw.submission_search(reddit, subreddit='R', limit=40000):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\psraw\base.py", line 71, in endpoint_func
    data = requests.get(url).json()['data']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 894, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

My code:

```
import praw, datetime, os, psraw

reddit = praw.Reddit('bot1')

subreddit = reddit.subreddit('R')

count = 0
try:
  for submission in psraw.submission_search(reddit, subreddit='R', limit=40000):
  count_coment = 0

  #get comments
    for comment in submission.comments:
        subid = submission.id
        comid = comment.id
        comauthor = comment.author
        com_body = comment.body.encode('utf-8').replace("\n", " ")
        comscore = comment.score
        com_date = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(comment.created_utc)
        string_com = '"{0}", "{1}", "{2}", "{3}", "{4}"\n'
        formatted_string_com = string_com.format(comid, comauthor, com_body, com_date, comscore)
        indexFile_comment = open('C:/Users/PycharmProjects/untitled/reddit_output_diabetes/' + subid + '.txt', 'a+')
        indexFile_comment.write(formatted_string_com)
        count_coment += 1
    print 'comment count: ', count_coment

    #get index

    date = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(submission.created_utc)
    _id = submission.id
    title = submission.title.encode('utf-8')
    text = submission.selftext.encode('utf-8').replace("\n", " ")
    author = submission.author
    score = submission.score
    string = '"{0}", "{1}", "{2}", "{3}", "{4}", "{5}"\n' 

    formatted_string = string.format(_id, title, text, author, date, score)
    count += 1
    indexFile = open('C:/Users/PycharmProjects/untitled/reddit_output/' + 'index.txt', 'a+')
    indexFile.write(formatted_string)

    print ("Successfuly writing in file")
    print count
    indexFile.close()
  print count
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
try:

.......put code here...

except ValueError:
   pass
   continue
```

Comment: you don't have to pass if you're using continue. Sorry for the late reply, I had troubles connecting to internet.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an error in parsing a particular comment. You can skip this comment and move on to the next one by handling it with try, except.

Put the code in:

```
try:

.......put code here...

except ValueError:
   pass
```

Comment: I put the try except, but the code just stuck in the beginning and doesn't run

Comment: Let me rephrase, it's running, but not returning any result.

Comment: That's strange given how you got those 7k results earlier.

Comment: I added try & except in the for loops. I just updated my code. But still got the same error after the 7250 result

Comment: And it didnt keep continuing and just stopped

Comment: @MichaelLin instead of telling it to `pass`, if you tell it to print something, does it print?

Comment: So I put try inside the first loop and add continue after pass. The code works.